# How can I enable JavaScript on every page at a site level?

Tags: master-page, delegate-control

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I would like to add the JS code for Google Analytics into the master page. I think a Delegate Control is the way to go, as we already have a Delegate Control in the Head section of the master page.

However, in this case there is a requirement to enable and disable the code per site, so would this still be the best approach?

I have put following code in .ascx file and writing in body tag instead of head tag.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
            //base.Render(writer);
            if (SPContext.Current != null) {
                SPFile file = SPContext.Current.File;
                if (file.Item != null) {
                    if (file.Item.Fields.ContainsField(KeywordKey) &&
                      file.Item[KeywordKey] != null &&
                      file.Item[KeywordKey].ToString() != string.Empty) {
                        writer.Write(string.Format(@"<META name=""keywords"" content=""{0}"">", file.Item[KeywordKey].ToString()));
                      }
                     if (file.Item.Fields.ContainsField(DescriptionKey) &&
                      file.Item[DescriptionKey] != null &&
                      file.Item[DescriptionKey].ToString() != string.Empty) {
                        writer.Write(string.Format(@"<META name=""description"" content=""{0}"">", file.Item[DescriptionKey].ToString()));
                     }


                }
            }
        }
```

i would like to write meta keywords on head section instead of body tags.

Thanks 
Ronak

Here's the Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Elements xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">; 
<!-- Use a sequence number lower than default of 100, so the custom control gets loaded before SharePoint controls --> 
<Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="50" ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/PhilaGov/MetaTagsKeyWords.ascx" /> 
</Elements>
```

Here's the Head section of Master Page

```
<HEAD runat="server">
<META Name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft SharePoint">
<META Name="progid" Content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="0">
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
<Title ID=onetidTitle><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id=PlaceHolderPageTitle runat="server"/></Title>
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" Defer="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
</HEAD>
```

UPDATE: Example page layout:

```
<%@ Page language="C#"   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">
            <!-- Styles for edit mode only-->
            <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/zz2_editMode.css %>" runat="server"/>
    </PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel>
    <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/rca.css %>" runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel runat="server" id="displaymodejs" PageDisplayMode="Display">
            <!-- JavaScript for to remove OverViewbox if its empty-->
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () { 
                          $(".overviewBox>div").filter(function (index) { return $(this).children().length < 1; }).parent().remove();
                    });
            </script>
    </PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
                <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                <div class="widget breadcrumb">
                  <asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" id="SiteMapPath1" SkipLinkText="" SiteMapProvider="CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode"></asp:SiteMapPath>  
             </div>
             <div class="widget pageTitle">
                    <h1>
                    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="HomePageTitleInTitleArea" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/></h1>
             </div>
             <div class="grid_15 colRight">
                 <div class="widget overviewBox">
                      <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="OverViewContent1" runat="server" 
                                                           InputFieldLabel="Content">  
                      </PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
                 </div>
                 <div class="widget WebPartEdit">
                      <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent1" runat="server" 
                                                           InputFieldLabel="Content">  
                      </PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
                 </div>
                 <div class="widget overviewBox">
                      <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="OverViewContent2" runat="server" 
                                                           InputFieldLabel="Content">  
                      </PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>

                 </div>
                 <div class="widget WebPartEdit">
                      <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent2" runat="server" 
                                                           InputFieldLabel="Content">  
                      </PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>

                 </div>
                 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="BottomZone" ID="BottomZone"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                 <PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel runat="server" id="editmodepanel1">
                    <!-- Add field controls here to bind custom metadata viewable and editable in edit mode only.-->
                    <SharePointWebControls:NoteField FieldName="MetaKeywords" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:NoteField>
                    <SharePointWebControls:NoteField FieldName="MetaDescription" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:NoteField>
                  </PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel>

             </div>
             <div class="grid_5 colLeft">
                  <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="LeftZone" ID="LeftZone"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
             </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your last edit, is it a separate question?

Comment: Nope James its same question also i would like render js too in head section with MetaKeywords and Description but somehow its writing to Body section ? should i put my code in CreateChildControls method instead.

Comment: If you put it in CreateChildControls nothing will be rendered as you're overriding the method the web part uses to render the controls. I would add the javascript lines in the same method you've pasted above. If you add the ASCX to the AdditionalPageHead control, it should go in the head tag.

Comment: True james i commented code for render events and doing CreatechildControls method and yes i am replacing AdditionalPageHead Delegate Control but dont know something weird is going on.

Comment: Please post the code in your elements.xml for the delegate control feature.

Comment: You've got a semicolon in there that shouldn't be, and I'd remove the comment as those are known to play up when inside elements.xml files.

Comment: Thanks James i don't see semicolon in elements.xml but i removed comment as per your suggestion.Thanks

Comment: James it still going in Body tag and also i have jQuery in pageLayout which i added in AdditionPageHead Content place holder that also going body section and if i try to put same code in Page_Load its say object reference is null when i try to activate feature.please advise

Comment: It sounds to me like your MasterPage has the AdditionalPageHead control inside the body tag for some reason. Has the masterpage been customised?

Comment: James it is out of box default.master page and its been customized but AdditionalPageHead is in Head section though something weird is going on Thanks

Comment: @JamesLove I tried to change master page and see how it works but same result.Thanks

Comment: @JamesLove Its Works ok with Teamsite...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete example of a working ASCX SharePoint DelegateControl. It adds the required Google Analytics stuff plus any meta keywords you define.

First, the feature.xml:

```
<Feature Id="INSERTYOURGUIDHERE"
  Title="Adds Google Analytics Counter (requires a Google Analytics ID)"
  Description="Activates feature for Google Analytics Web counter"
  Version="1.0.0.0"
  Scope="Web"
  Hidden="FALSE"
  ActivateOnDefault="FALSE"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ElementManifests>
      <ElementManifest Location="elementManifest.xml"/>
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Second, the elementManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" ControlSrc="~/_controltemplates/GoogleAnalytics.ascx"></Control>
</Elements>
```

Third, the GoogleAnalytics.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" compilationMode="Always" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" %>
<%
    string keywords = "keyword-1,keyword-2";
    string idString = "UA-1234567-8";
    string requestProtocol = "http://www.";

    try
    {
        if (keywords != "")
        {
            // Add keywords meta tag
            Response.Write("\n\n<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"" + keywords + "\" />\n");

            // Write debug output, use Microsoft "DebugView" locally on the server to watch the output 
            Trace.WriteLine("meta keywords: " + keywords);
        }

        if (idString != "")
        {
            // Check if HTTPS (SSL) is used to request this page
            if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                // Set appropriate SSL url
                requestProtocol = "https://ssl.";
            }

            // Add async script load to page head
            Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '" + idString + "']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);(function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = '" + requestProtocol + "google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();</script>");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
    }
%>
```

You need to replace the `keywords` and `idString` variables with values of your choice and also create a valid feature id to pop into `Feature Id="INSERTYOURGUIDHERE"`.

Also note the line starting with `Trace.WriteLine`. It shows how a simple tracing can be implemented and watched using the Microsoft DebugView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) utility.

You can use just a simple text editor (I prefer the free and open source Notepad++) and the Codeplex WSPBuilder to wrap it into a WSP and you're ready to deploy.

Once done, activate the feature on each SharePoint Website (SPWeb) of your choice and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks Sig is it ok to use Inline code in .ascx meaning do i need to tell sharepoint is it safe to use inline code ?

Comment: Thanks Sig your code works but problem is it not writing to head section but body.Thanks

Comment: Check your masterpage. It should have only one AdditionalPageHead inside the HEAD section.

Comment: Thanks Sig it has only one AdditionalPageHead but still its pushing in Body section no matter what master page i use.Thanks

Comment: Which SharePoint version do you use? MOSS 2007 or WSS v3? Which service pack and cumulative update package? Did you try it with default.master on a standard Teamsite? Does it work when you hit the default.aspx homepage of a Teamsite?

Comment: I have moss 2007 SP2 nope i haven't tried in team site. i am trying on Publishing site.let me try on team site and see if its works.Thanks

Comment: In teamSite its even worst i am not able to see in body section too.Thanks

Comment: Let me double check on one of my development virtual machines...

Comment: if i use your code instead of code behind file meaning not onRender method then everything looks fine with TeamSite but for Publishing site it still goes to body section interestig....Thanks

Comment: Its Confirm that it works with teamsite but not with publishing site.....

Comment: Ok, just checked on a WSS v3 SP2 Teamsite and got it working. Now off to copy a MOSS 2007 virtual machine from an old backup to test it there.

Comment: well its working with teamsite template but not with publishing site template which i really wants....Thanks

Comment: Guys, we have a chat site for elaborate discussions like this. Comments are not for this kind of conversations.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop a Delegate Control for the Head Section, by creating a SharePoint feature. That SharePoint feature can be enabled and disabled according to the Sites.

File -> New Project -> SharePoint Empty Project.

Add New Class and change its base class to System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl

Override required methods like OnLoad,CreateChildControls or Render.

Add New Module with `Elements.xml` and add the below tag. Ensure that the Safe property is set to true

```
<Control Id="AdditionalPageHead"  Sequence="100" ControlClass="addedclassFullName" ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"  ></Control>
```

Instead of adding a class we can use an UserControl and refer it in ControlSrc property of Control tag in place of ControlClass and ControlAssembly.

Finally, deploy the feature.

Here is good [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470880.aspx)

[Here some best practices for using delegate controls in 2007](http://www.devcow.com/blogs/adnrg/archive/2007/12/14/sharepoint-delegate-controls-in-sharepoint-2007-best-practices.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Styler for your reply i did that but somehow its not working.i create feature to replace AdditionalPageHead Delegate control in master page with .ascx which register js in code behind but its not working.

Comment: Delegate Controls can be frustrating as when they don't load they don't do anything, not even log anything. Just keep trying different cases of _CONTROLTEMPLATES in the feature element, have your ASCX spit some Literal text out to see if the codebehind is failing for some reason... This method does work because I use it, but sometimes takes a bit of loving to get to work.

Comment: I agree with James but I have update some steps for you to see if you could find some missing links in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for Your Help and suggestion now its working.I reset master Page and all check to reset all sites and subsites to reset to masterpage settings and its working.

Thanks 
Ronak

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I'm not nuts ;) I've just finished testing on a MOSS 2007 virtual machine and couldn't reproduce your issue using a publishing site, so I suspected a masterpage issue. Would you mind marking one of the two answers as your preferred answer?

Comment: @Sig i will do it today still there are some weird issue is going on doing more testing on it...will let you guys know wats going on ....Thanks for help

Comment: Alright Guys Now i know wats going on first thing there is no problem with master page and it also work fine with out of Box PageLayouts but it does not like PageLayout that i have created in SPD 2007.I have Content type with two site columns named MetaKeywords and MetaDescription that content authors can modify and i have created PageLayouts based on this content types.i have no idea whats Problem going on.please advise Thanks

Comment: Can you post the sourcecode of such a page layout? I suspect SPD is messing it up (wouldn't be the first time, you know).

Comment: @sig i did but formatting looks bad though i don't know how to put code in here in nice format....Thanks again for looking into this...

Comment: I've reformatted your code for better readability. As far as I can see, your page layout contains a asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" which is causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks Sig Weber for your reply Outofbox pagelayouts like article left,right used same Placeholder but works with them as it should

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys nothing do with master page,Pagelayouts.Actually i have created pageLayouts on some other environment and copy on my local but didnt copy master page from that environment and sharepoint somehow i don't like that but its all good now..Thanks

Comment: Do you think you guys could move all of the information from comments into an answer? That way, it will be easier for other people in the future.